# No Compatible GPUs found ... Blender 2.8 User Preferences

Tags: customization, gpu

No Compatible GPUs found ...

Seen in Blender 2.8 User Preferences

System ... Cycles Render Devices ...

---

Version 2.78 recognizes the GPU.  I understand that 2.78 and 2.8 have different requirements.  Yet I would like to rule out other problems.

Is there any action I can take to correct this situation?
Is there any steps I can take to investigate this situation.  In the past I have rarely had to consider a situation like this with the GPU.

Windows 10 OS,

Nvidia 670M GPU Laptop. GeForce GTX 670M    Compute Capability 2.1

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus#compute

---

System Info provided by Blender 2.8 as a text file.

Excerpt

---

Blender 2.80 (sub 75) System Information =

Blender:

version: 2.80 (sub 75), branch: master, commit date: 2019-07-29 14:47, hash: f6cb5f54494e, type: 
build date: 2019-07-29, 09:44 AM
platform: Windows

OpenGL:

renderer:   'GeForce GTX 670M/PCIe/SSE2'

vendor:     'NVIDIA Corporation'

version:    '4.5.0 NVIDIA 382.05'

---

Some links that were not particularly helpful to me

https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/

https://devtalk.blender.org/t/hardware-requirements-for-blender-2-8/3440

Comment: Sorry for the bad news, but @rjg is right. I had a similar issue and had to upgrade my GPU.

Comment: ... I M

Comment: @JodySmith.  Would you like to comment on the choice between buying a different computer (not necessarily manufacturer new) and adding another  used graphic card to the waste management system?  I think we might be able to survive the open mouths regarding hardware discussion, because (low cost / use based software) which requires hardware purchases can cause .  I have replaced GPUs on desktops ... but not a laptop.

Answer (score 2):

The requirements for GPU rendering are higher than the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender.

> **Supported Graphics Cards**
>
> These requirements are for basic Blender operation, rendering using the GPU requires slightly different [requirements](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware).

The manual states that CUDA compute capability 3.0 or higher is required for GPU rendering. Graphics cards that do not meet that requirement will not be listed in the preferences.

> NVIDIA CUDA is supported for GPU rendering with NVIDIA graphics cards. Blender supports graphics cards with compute capability 3.0 and higher. To make sure your GPU is supported, see the [list of NVIDIA graphics cards](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) with the compute capabilities and supported graphics cards.

The Nvidia website lists the GeForce GTX 670M with a compute capability of 2.1, which does not meet the requirements for GPU rendering.

Comment: What timing.  So immediate. We both listed the compute capability within minutes of each other I believe.  I will mark your response within 48 hours.  I do not want to hear such distasteful news, thus the slow hand.