# Mac Pro (tower Mid 2010) Nvidia Quadra k5000 not recognised by blender 2.82 as a GPU

Tags: osx

Morning...
I am trying to squeeze another year out of a 10 year old Mac before making it a doorstop, seat, or beer cooler...
I have a pretty fast Nvidia card (k5000) which has Cuda processors from what I can make of it...
but when I look in the system preferences of blender, it says that is does not see any cuda processors...

is there a workaround to take advantage of the card speeding up my work flow?

cheers

r

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155112/no-compatible-gpus-found-blender-2-8-user-preferences

Comment: Should work according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Quadro#CUDA (requirement is Cuda 3.0)

Comment: What version of macOS are you using?

Comment: Have you looked up the Compute Capability as advertised by NVidia?